# Get precision of cout

Tags: c++, precision, cout

I can set precision of `cout` output using

```
cout.precision(precision_value);
```

how can I *get* the precision value, which is used by `cout` already?
I can't find any other related function in `cout` [description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/).

The related problem I faced is how can I change cout precision for some part of a code only (so it need to be reset afterwards to exact previous value).

I tryed:

```
//save original cout flags
std::ios_base::fmtflags coutFlags = cout.flags();

cout.precision(1);
cout.setf(ios::fixed);

 // code

cout.flags(coutFlags);
```

but this doens't work.

Comment: why not use a variable and change it each tim?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision

Comment: `cout.setf(ios::fixed);` overwrites ***all*** flags, and not just the flag of interest. I made the same mistake recently: [istringstream not honoring base?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33708337).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function is [overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision). Both overloads return the precision that was set before the call to the function. `cout.precision()` may be what you want to query it.

To save it and set it back later:

```
auto old_precision = cout.precision(temp_precision);
// do stuff
cout.precision(old_precision);
```

Comment: oh, I totally missed the return value. Was looking for another function. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With the function [precision()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision).

```
int main() {
  std::cout << std::cout.precision() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```