# istringstream not honoring base?

Tags: c++, radix, istream

I'm trying to remediate some Coverity findings on tainted values due to the use of `atoi` and `atof`. I switched to an `istringstream`, but its not producing expected results for bases other than 10.

If I switch to base 16, enter 0xa and avoid the `iss.ignore(2);`, then the result is 0:

```
$ ./tt.exe 0xa
X: 0
```

If I switch to base 16, enter 0xa and utilize the `iss.ignore(2);`, then the result is an exception:

```
$ ./tt.exe 0xa
'0xa' is not a value
```

I visited [CPP Reference on istringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=istringstream) as recommended by @πάντα, but it does not discuss a limitation in this context.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Or, how can I get this to work as expected?

---

```
$ cat tt.cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T StringToValue(const std::string& str) {
  std::istringstream iss(str);
  T value;

  if (str.length() >= 2) {
    if (str[0] == '0' && (str[1] =='X' || str[1] =='x'))
      {
        iss.setf(std::ios_base::hex);
        iss.ignore(2);
      }
  }
  iss >> value;

  if (iss.fail())
    throw runtime_error("'" + str +"' is not a value");

  return value;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
    {
      int x = StringToValue<int>(argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "ZZZ...");
      cout << "X: " << x << endl;
    }
  catch(const runtime_error& ex)
    {
      cerr << ex.what() << endl;
      return 1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `0x` prefix when reading in the digits.

Comment: Ah I see, you've placed the `ignore(2)` there.

Comment: The usual way is something like `iss >> hex >> value;`.

Comment: Can you make a _minimal_ testcase please?

Comment: So the problem in that `atoi` and friends not handle errors? Then why not use `std::stoi` and others, they throw exceptions on error.

Comment: @user1034749 - we support ancient compilers. In fact, I just finished testing on Fedora 1 with GCC 3.2. (We are not like browsers and Apple operating systems).

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - that is a minimal test case. In fact, I created it just for you :)

Comment: @jww: It's not though, which is why you blamed istringstream when in fact istringstream extracts hexadecimals just fine. The bug is in your code somewhere, and you haven't performed enough debugging to isolate it.

Comment: @jww If it is ancient compiler, than why not `sscanf(str, "%X", &int_val) == 1`? With `gcc -Wformat=error` and `coverity` you will be completely safe, and not have to deal with bugs in old `c++` runtime.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - thanks. All the code is above. Feels free to let me know how I screwed up `iss.setf(std::ios_base::hex);` when using `0xa`. That's the reason I provided everything I am doing, and even showed other attempts to get it to work.

Comment: @jww: Off-hand I can't see it (other than the one bug I pointed out in comments below my answer). Perhaps when I get back from where I'm going in a minute I'll have a deeper look.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - *"...I'll have a deeper look"* - thanks. Its more a morbid curiosity more than anything else. If you don't have time, then that's fine too. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @user1034749 - its a C++ project, and it has high integrity requirements. As soon as the less-safe functions like `sscanf` are used, then it triggers a security defect. It also causes some folks to fail an audit (if they have C&A requirements). We could probably use `sscanf_s` from ISO/IEC TR 24731-2 on Windows, but then Apple, BSD, Linux and some Unixes would need a separate implementation that does not trigger a security finding, and it passes a C&A audit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks again for the help. Sorry about wasting your time with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're completely overthinking this. Reading a value in hexadecimal notation is easy.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
   {
      int x = 0;
      std::istringstream is("0xa");
      is >> std::hex >> x;
      assert(x == 10);
   }
   {
      int x = 0;
      std::istringstream is("a");
      is >> std::hex >> x;
      assert(x == 10);
   }
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3633c81bccc7e78f))

---

Regardless, I can identify two problems with your code.

### 1. Incorrect use of `std::ios_base::setf`

You're replacing the stream's entire flagset with *only* `std::ios_base::hex`. The flags are not just for numeric bases. To do that, you need to mask out everything else to prevent unsetting other, unrelated, but necessary flags (I don't know what they are):

```
iss.setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios::basefield);
```

This is why `iss >> std::hex` is so much easier.

It's also why you should have constructed a minimal testcase consisting of *nothing but a test of `iss.setf`* before posting!

### 2. Broken logic

The case where input is just "a" skips that statement entirely, as it is conditional on the first two characters being "0x".

Move it to just before the `iss >> value`, I would.

---

You can see your fixed code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b78ba203c5aeac07) but, as explored at the start of my answer, the whole switching-on-leading-`"0x"` thing is unnecessary, so most of your code can just be removed.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas why explicitly setting the base did not work as expected? It may help me in the future.

Comment: @jww: I didn't look into it. Now that I have proven with a minimal testcase that `istringstream` works just fine, you can continue your debugging to find out. :)

Comment: It looks like it might help others, too: [Get precision of cout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20374137). Thanks again.